# How to setup step colorbar in matlab?

Tags: matlab, colorbar, contourf

I want to change the default color bar (jet color) generated by Matlab, especially the step of the color (just like the figure below). How to do that?

Here's my code

```
[hC hC] = contourf(interp2(sal,2,'spline'),[0:0.5:5]);
set(hC,'LineStyle','none','YTick',0:4);
colorbar;
```

**[image]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to reduce the number of colors in the contour plot and colorbar then you can set a new colormap with a reduce color set.

```
%Get 10 colors from jet
numColors = 10;
colormap(jet(numColors))  
data = peaks;
contourf(data)
% Optionally you can set yTicks in conjunction with the number of items in your colormap to line up
colorbar('YTick',linspace(min(data(:)),max(data(:)),numColors+1))
```

[image]

EDIT:
If you want more control over where the contour lines are drawn then use the function in this form `countourf(data,v)` where `v` is an monotonically increasing vector of your desired contour levels.  Example:

```
contourf(data,linspace(-7,8,numColors))
c = colorbar('YTick',linspace(-7,8,numColors+1));
```

The will draw 10 contour lines at -7, -5.33, -3.66 ... 8.  Replace -7 and 8 with whatever you wish ex. min/max of data or whatever makes sense for your application

Comment: It's good answer, working perfectly. But with your script `colorbar('YTick',linspace(min(data(:)),max(data(:)),numColors+1))`, its will show the min and max data. How to define specific step for example (6,4,2,0,-2,-4,-6)..@Aero Engy

Comment: See my EDIT above.  Basically use contourf(data,v) where v is [6,4,2,0,-2,-4,-6] or what makes sense for your data set.  I would probably match the numColors to however many contour lines you wish to draw.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the color bar properties by using:

```
c=colorbar;
c.Ticks=[vector of tick locations]
```

or alternately you could try

```
c.Limits=[min max]
```

See the MATLAB documentation for colorbar properties: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar-properties.html?refresh=true

this explains color bar customization in more detail